# strtok_r Returns Error in tokenizing String

Tags: c, strtok

According to the `strtok_r` man pages:

> RETURN VALUE
> The  strtok()  and strtok_r() functions return a pointer
> to the next token, or NULL if there are no more tokens.

I tried to compile this function I wrote to tokenize strings with tabs, spaces and `\n` as delimiters

```
#include "program.h"
#include <string.h>

/**
 * tokenize_line - Tokenize command input plus any other arguments
 * @s: line to parse
 * @tokens: buffer for filling
 *
 * Return: 1 if success, 0 for failure
 */
int tokenize_line(char *s, char *tokens[])
{
        int i, status;
        char *token, *hold;

        token = strtok_r(s, " \t\n", &hold);
        status = check_if_comment(&token);
        if (status == 1)
                return (0);

        for (i = 0; token && i < 2; i++)
        {
                tokens[i] = token;

                token = strtok_r(NULL, " \t\n", &hold);
        }

        return (1);
}
```

compiling it with `gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c89 filename_with_this_function.c` gives me this error;

```
In function ‘tokenize_line’:                 
  error: implicit declaration of function
 ‘strtok_r’; did you mean ‘strtok’? [-Werror=implicit-function-de
claration]                                                       
   15 |  token = strtok_r(s, " \t\n", &hold);                    
      |          ^~~~~~~~                                        
      |          strtok                 
rror: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’
 makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversio
n]                                                               
   15 |  token = strtok_r(s, " \t\n", &hold);                    
      |        ^                        
error: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’
 makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversio
n]                                                               
   24 |   token = strtok_r(NULL, " \t\n", &hold);                
      |         ^
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: It seems kind of odd to pass the address of the pointer to `check_if_comment`.  Does it change the pointer?

Comment: Aside: we don't see what `check_if_comment` is but `status = check_if_comment(&token);` looks suspicious. Should it be `status = check_if_comment(token);` ?

Comment: @Weather Vane the function `check_if_comment` uses memory address to `token` instead of the value contained in the memory address of `token` to check for comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strtok_r` function is not part of the C89 standard.

You need to remove the `-pedantic -std=c89` options from the command line.

Comment: Oh okay. how else can I resolve this problem without withdrawing the `-pedantic -std=c89` option from the compilation?

Comment: @greez' Don't use `strtok_r`.